# Como hacer efecto maquina de escribir con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy creando un efecto tipo maquina de escribir con jquery, funciona bien el efecto, va escribiendo carácter por carácter sin ningún problema. Pero me gustaría que el efecto igual funcionen con etiquetas tipo **strong** o **small**

Como puedo lograr que dicha función contemple las etiquetas y escriba el texto o parte de el en negrita según corresponda.

Ejemplo si escribo el siguiente texto con sus etiquetas me las va escribiendo y solo se muestra en negrita cuando se termina de escribir la etiqueta, pero me gustaría que se escriba ya en negrita desde el comienzo de la palabra.

```
En <strong>Iliusterra</strong> encontraras el servicio que buscas para una <strong>Energía Sustentable</strong>, desde <strong>Asesorías para el desarrollo de proyectos</strong>, hasta los mismos <strong>Servicios de Instalación</strong>.
```

Adjunto el código utilizado

```
var maquina = $('.maquina');
maquina_escribir("En Iliusterra encontraras el servicio que buscas para una Energía Sustentable, desde Asesorías para el desarrollo de proyectos, hasta los mismos Servicios de Instalación.",60,maquina);

function maquina_escribir(text,tiempo,etiqueta){
    var arrayCaracteres = text.split('');
    var escribiendo = '';
    etiqueta.html('');
    var cont = 0;
    var escribir = setInterval(function(){
        escribiendo += arrayCaracteres[cont];
        etiqueta.html(escribiendo);
        cont++;     
        if(cont === arrayCaracteres.length){
            clearInterval(escribir);
        }       
    }, tiempo);
    console.log(arrayCaracteres);
}
```